# Updating PayPal Braintree token in PayPal console

Tags: paypal

I am using https://javadoc.io/doc/com.braintreepayments.gateway/braintree-java/latest/com/braintreegateway/BraintreeGateway.html to create a BraintreeGateway object.

I need to update my development and production tokens. If I go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/ I can see a Generate Sandbox Access Token button on the Sandbox tab, but if I click the Live tab there is no such button - I can see an email under the Live Account heading and if I click on it I can see the live access token with a reset icon next to it. Is resetting the token right now my only option? Am I able to create a new token and phase out the old one safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one Braintree access token per account, so for live mode this corresponds to the live PayPal account you signed into https://developer.paypal.com with.

Refreshing an account's access token will replace it with a new one, invalidating the old one -- so the only 'safe' way to do this is to schedule a brief maintenance window in your lowest traffic period.

(For sandbox mode, your developer account allows you to create as many different sandbox business accounts as you want for testing, and so each one can have its own Braintree access token.)